# html stack order

Tags: html, css, stack

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>HTML</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <style type="text/css">

    h1 {
      font-size: 2em;
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    p {
      border: 3px solid blue;
      margin-top: -50px;
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>QUESTION</h1>
  <p>The header text in the preceding h1 element is behind this
    paragraph's text (as expected), but on top of this paragraph's
    background and border (not expected).
  </p> 

</body>

</html>
```

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKHc9/

Why isn't the paragraph's background and border rendered on top of the header like the content is?

Comment: See [this page](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp). Does it work as expected? If so, please post more information on your code as well as the browsers that are affected.

Comment: Which browser, what doctype, is that it? If that's your *entire* code, then the browser is probably entering quirksmode and doing funky things.

Comment: @zzzzBov: No, that's not my entire code, just a snippet; I have all the other necessary crap to go along ;)

Comment: @Bill, please answer my comment above so I can help.

Comment: @Kevin, OK, I'll have a look.

Comment: Yes, this page is consistent with what I originally believed. The div 'B' background is above the div 'A' content (with z-index unset), so it works as expected here.

Comment: @Bill, then you will need to post more of your code as the example above cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: @OK Kevin, I've included all the code in my OP.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with how browsers are handling negatively margined blocks. I cannot find reference to why it would work in this manner in the spec either. I would hope that someone more educated on the matter can post and help us both understand this.

Comment: I agree, it probably has something to do with negative margins. As Patrick pointed out, making the paragraph's position relative makes things behave as expected. Well, at least I know it's not just me! Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the two elements are each **in-flow, non-positioned, block-level elements in the same stacking context**.

Two in-flow, non-positioned blocks aren't strictly "above" or "below" each other -- their **contents and backgrounds stack separately**.

Adding `position: relative` will make an element positioned (with `z-index: auto`) and place it above non-positioned elements in the same stacking context: it will be rendered at step 8 in the painting algorithm below.

---

If you read the CSS2 spec's [Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) closely, you will see that this is correct behavior.

In-flow, non-positioned, block-level elements within the same stacking context first have all their backgrounds rendered, then all their contents. Their backgrounds are above positioned elements with a negative `z-index` and below everything else.

The relevant steps in the painting algorithm:

> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. ...
> 4. For all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order: If the element is a block, list-item, or other block equivalent:
>
>    1. background color of element.
>    2. background image of element.
>    3. border of element.
> 5. ...
> 6. ...
> 7. ... for all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order:
>
>    1. ...
>    2. ... for each line box of that element:
>
>       1. For each box that is a child of that element, in that line box, in tree order:
>
>          1. ...
>          2. ...
>          3. ...
>          4. For inline elements:
>
>             1. For all the element's in-flow, non-positioned, inline-level children
>                  that are in this line box, and all runs of text inside the element that is on this line
>                  box, in tree order:
>
>                1. If this is a run of text, then:
>
>                   1. ...
>                   2. ...
>                   3. the text.
>                   4. ...
> 8. ...
> 9. ...
> 10. ...

Floated and positioned elements are always "atomic" -- their backgrounds and contents will be rendered together in a single step (either step 3, 5, 8 or 9). But in-flow, non-positioned block elements within the same stacking context have all their backgrounds rendered (in step 4), then have all their contents rendered (in step 7).

In this case, for in-flow, non-positioned sibling elements H1 and P (H1 before P in the tree), step 4 renders the H1 background and then the P background, then step 7 renders the H1 content and then the P content.

Comment: While that page does visualize that, [this page](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp) and [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) show no rules that agree with your statement. As far as I understand, the entire box is always rendered above previous boxes when `z-index` is implied.

Comment: Yes, that's a good link, and a good explanation. I've never heard of that distinction between content and backgrounds/borders when it comes to stack level -- Kevin doubts if this is true, though...

Comment: @Kevin, yes, what you're saying is what I thought to be true.

Comment: @Bill, I'm not denying what that page explains. What that page explains is absolutely true. However, the layering model there is a different context.

Comment: These two elements have the same z-index. In your example, http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp, the "second" element is a child, not a sibling. A child will render on top of its parent. The parent-child relationship gives us the "implied" z-index you are talking about. We don't have that between sibling elements.

Comment: According to the second link, this is not the case. My understanding of stacking order of boxes is that boxes are always atomic unto themselves, z-index is applied, and then tree is applied onto that (meaning order of definition on the page). If you have something that refutes that, please post it. The current page you posted discusses the layering order internal to boxes, which is totally separate from stacking order.

Comment: @Patrick, but div 'B' is a sibling of div 'A', and its background is above A's content, so how do you explain that?

Comment: Also, you seemed to have reviewed the first link incorrectly. `#dd-demo1`, `#dd-demo2`, and `#dd-demo3` are all siblings. In the example on that page all 3 have `background`s and `border`s. In all cases, when stacked against siblings with the ssame `z-index`, the border, background color, and content flow below the next sibling.

Comment: "z-index is applied, and then tree is applied onto that (meaning order of definition on the page)" => This produces the behavior I describe. "z-index is applied" produces a tie (no explicit or implicit difference in z-ordering). Going to the "tree", the element that appears later in the source "wins". Thus the P content renders over the H1 content. Moving on the background, the P background also wins over the H1 background. But the P background does not "win" over the H1 content, because they have the exact same z-index and within the same z-index content appears over backgrounds.

Comment: for the last time, layers in a box are not taken into account when stacking order is applied. No box can bleed another box, period. If you have something other that proves me wrong in this regard, please post it. I've posted the css rules and a test case page that prove my claims.

Comment: @Bill, if you add `p { position: relative; }` to the styles above, the H1 content is obscured. This is very interesting. I'm not yet sure what to make of it.

Comment: @Kevin, I don't want to prove you wrong if you're right. I'm trying to explain the browser behavior observed. It may well be the case that the browser is not implementing the box model correctly. I'd have to read the spec very carefully to make a decision on that, and I'm out of time. I stand by my answer as a good explanation of what I think the browser is doing. Whether the browser is behaving correctly, I do not know.

Comment: @Patrick, I understand and hope you didn't feel like I was attacking you. It just seemed as if you were trying to prove me wrong without any proof. I have been messing around with it as well this entire time and am now able to confirm that, while it is not documented anywhere that I can find in the spec, most, if not all, browsers are implementing this in the same manner. Also, I found the original work for your image, I'd suggest you add it to you answer as it is a very detailed description of everything we've discussed in these comments.

Comment: @Patrick, [original work](http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/layers.html). Also update my vote ;)

Comment: @Patrick, yes, making the paragraph position relative gives the expected stack order. I don't understand why that would matter either.

Comment: @Kevin, thank you, that is quite civil of you. :) That source article suggests a case where something like this can happen: "When you reach the lowest level in a stack, instead of elements stacking one on top of each other the parent element splits itself. Elements with negative z-index stack in order, not on top of the parent element, but on top of its background and border but under its content." Whether that is actually proper and whether it should apply here are not questions I can readily answer. All in all, there is more to this question than meets the eye.

Comment: I read the CSS2 painting algorithm closely, and found that there is a reason that browsers do it this way: it is correct.

Comment: @Patrick, do you have a link to that? I've obviously missed something. Thanks.

Comment: I refer to [your second link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). Floated and positioned elements are always "atomic" -- their backgrounds and contents will be rendered together in a single step (either step 3, 5, 8 or 9). But in-flow, non-positioned block elements within the same stacking context have all their backgrounds rendered (in step 4), then have all their contents rendered (in step 7). So, for in-flow, non-positioned elements H1 and P (H1 before P in the tree), step 4 renders the H1 background and then the P background, then step 7 renders the H1 content and then the P content.

Answer (score 0):

The default stacking order for HTML elements is that elements later in the code are "above" earlier elements.

Add this to the CSS:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
```

Comment: The OP's quetion was: `Why isn't the paragraph's background and border rendered on top of the header like the content is?` What you have said confirms what the OP is confused about. While position relative might help bring the `p` `background` and `border` above the header, he's confused why the rules state that they should already be there.

Answer (score -1):

If even after following the above inputs, your code didn't work please try the way mentioned below to find out the issue.

Open the page in chrome browser>right click>Inspect>Console

In my case the bootsrap stylesheet reference and jquery were wrongly placed, on the Console I found this error and fixed it.

Regards,
Mukul Bawa

Comment: Why do you think that this is the situation in the question?