# Sibling div splitting background from text with position:static

Tags: html, css

Two sibling divs (`#one` and `#two`) each containing some text.

I move `#two` with negative margin-top and would expect it to cover `#one`, but while text gets positioned in front of `#one`, the background get's positioned  underneath.

This happens only when `#one` has `display:inline-block`.

```css
div {
    width:110px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:55px;
    font-weight:900;
    text-align:center
}
#one {
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
}
#two {
    background:purple;
    color:pink;
    margin-top:-90px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/cyct1dxe/)**

If anybody could give an explanation it would be appreciated

---

**EDIT**:
I'm not looking for a workaround but would like to understand how `inline-block` element is being rendered

Comment: What is it that you're expecting and what do you need explained? Also, what is your goal?

Comment: @j08691 since it's being rendered after the first div (both with `position:static` ), logically I would expect that div `#two` totally overlaps `#one`

Comment: From the other hand: https://jsfiddle.net/cyct1dxe/3/ and https://jsfiddle.net/cyct1dxe/4/ The issue is not only in inline-block.

Comment: Some reading is required - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html#painting-order

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5276735/161182

Comment: @PatrickFisher 's answer is the one that best describes this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Both elements are in the same layer, as in, they are siblings. This puts them on the same plane. So in effect your two layers are sitting like this:

> Text                   Text
>   _ _ _ _ _            _ _ _ _ _

It would be safe to assume that the second the two elements would be stacked on top of the other, so when you make them both occupy the same space, it's merging them together like this:

> Text               
>     Text
>   _ _ _ _ _       
>      _ _ _ _ _

Which is sort of like have two decks of cards and then pushing them together.

Now this is all based upon both of them being their default display value of `block`, which makes them exactly the same:

```css
div {
    width:110px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:55px;
    font-weight:900;
    text-align:center
}
#one {
    background:yellow;
}
#two {
    background:purple;
    color:pink;
    margin-top:-90px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
```

Now what you're seeing is when you put the first one as `display:inline-block;`. Inline elements will always display above Block elements because that's the way the [Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html) rolls, however that will only apply to the element, not the text content so that's why it's displaying like:

> Text
>   Text               
>   _ _ _ _ _       
>      _ _ _ _ _

```css
div {
    width:110px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:55px;
    font-weight:900;
    text-align:center
}
#one {
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
}
#two {
    background:purple;
    color:pink;
    margin-top:-90px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
```

I hope that helps understand why it's displaying the way it is. Of course if you change their z-index like the three people below have suggested then you put them on different planes like so:

> Text
>   _ _ _ _ _ 
>               Text
>            _ _ _ _ _

Comment: from definition each box should create it's own stacking content; probably the tricky part is that being `position:static`  `z-index` has no effect, and no stack is created.

Comment: @maioman You would obviously need to change the `position` value, if you can of course.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5276735/1824363) which doesn't exactly follow your scenario but it is close and has good information. Mainly this [Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html), this will tell you how HTML renders elements.

I normally fix it by setting `position: relative;` on the offending elements.

```css
div {
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center
}
#one, #two {
  position: relative;
}
#one {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
}
#two {
  background: purple;
  color: pink;
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add a `position: relative` and relevant `z-index` values, that should work...

```css
div {
    width:110px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:55px;
    font-weight:900;
    text-align:center
}
#one {
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#two {
    background:purple;
    color:pink;
    margin-top:-90px;
    margin-left:20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center
}
#one {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#two {
  background: purple;
  color: pink;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
```